# Loading iframe when visible using Jquery and LazyLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, lazy-loading

I am trying to load an animation within an iframe that I did on Google web Designer.

I haven't been able to make it work. I downloaded Jquery.js, and Jquery.lazy.min.js from here: http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/

This is my attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function() {
        $('.lazy').Lazy();
    });

</script>

<iframe class="lazy" data-src="slider1/slider1.html" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="300px"></iframe>
```

It doesn't work at all, the animation is not loaded whatsoever!

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lazy.iframe.min.js"></script>` should be enough assuming it works at all. Hit F12 to see if there are console errors

Comment: I get two: 1) "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" 2) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined ... I uploaded only the .js file (jquery.lazy.min.js) via FTP, is there anything else I should do?

Comment: JQuery.js has of course also to exist in that folder

Comment: It's there too. Did I isntall it wrong? i didn't use Bower, i basically just moved the jquery lazy folder via FTP.

Comment: Look in the network tab to see a 404 in the jQuery.js - I assume the lazy folder contains what you expect